# TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_DISCONNECTED in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8

Got the following error message when I run my project in Xcode 8:

> TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_DISCONNECTED in response to state failed and error Error Domain=kNWErrorDomainPOSIX Code=61 "Connection refused" UserInfo={NSDescription=Connection refused}

Here is the code cause this problem:

@implementation UIImageView (LoadAsyn)

```
+ (void) loadFromURL: (NSURL*) url callback:(void (^)(UIImage *image))callback {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            callback(image);
        });
    });
}
```

By the way, I checked with my url. There is no problem at all.Somebody mentioned `dataWithContentsOfURL` can only be used to access local resources. But here is the what Apple said:

> A data object containing the data from the location specified by aURL. Returns nil if the data object could not be created.

It didn't say we can't use it for remote url and I used this for a quite long time already in my previous Xcode.

Any idea? Thanks.

**P.S:**

Sorry, I think I could be wrong. Based on the latest document of Apple:

> Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.

But I used this in an async way (in a thread other than main thread). I'm a bit confused and I'll do more researches on this.

Comment: I solved the issue by using AFNetworking. But I still don't quite understand with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Though you called it from background thread but this method is synchronised with main thread. It does not depends on the thread it is called from.

Comment: Really ? But the Apple document didn't mention it runs in main thread. It only says it can block the current thread. But I run it in a thread other than main thread. Thanks anyway.